# Writing a wrapper for cd - echo custom error messages or let cd's error msgs bubble up?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash function which basically wraps the cd command, adding some additional functionality.

This works fine, but as soon as something goes wrong (given path does not exist, the user doesn't have enough rights to enter a directory), the user is presented the error messages from cd.

Simple example:

```
$ echo $PWD
/home/helpermethod/workspace
$ up helpermethod # goes up to the first directory named helpermethod
$ echo $PWD
/home/helpermethod
$ up foo
bash: cd: /home/helpermethod/foo: No such file or directory
```

Is it okay to let those error messages bubble up, or shall I present the user with something more meaningful (and hide the actual implementation)?

**EDIT**

The function is going to be used by (hopefully) a lot of users.

**EDIT 2**

What the function does... `up` let's the user enter a basename of a directory above the current directory.

So if you have e.g.

$ echo $PWD
   /home/helpermethod/workspace/java

and you type

```
$ up home
```

the `PWD` is taken, and the part after the basename is stripped from `PWD`.

It also allows to enter a "path" to walk, if there a multiple directory with the same basename:

```
$ echo $PWD
/foo/baz/foo/bar
$ up baz foo # go to foo, which lies above baz
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends solely on your requirements. Are you writing this function for yourself? If so, it only depends on your preference. Are you writing it for someone else? Then it depends on their preferences and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you provide your own error messages depends on whether the ones provided by `cd` are meaningful in the context of the functionality of your function. Since you haven't described the feature set of your function, it's impossible to tell if some messages might make more sense if they were replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle the common error conditions yourself, to give a better error, then let the uncommon ones bubble up.  For example, typing the wrong string is likely to happen frequently, and the error message doesn't give much information.  Much better to say: `No such directory foo in current directory hierarchy` or something.  In fact, this seems like an error condition you should get almost for free as you try to do your string processing.  But then you're probably fine letting `cd` error out if you there's a permission error, or if the whole tree disappeared in the meantime, or something else.